# Как объединить массив объектов в один массив в js

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная `res`, которая помещает в себя массив объектов, значение `id` которых равно значению `resultFinal` (при работе это значение меняется: каждый раз получаем новый массив объектов, а точнее массив из одного объекта):

```js
const res = cards.filter((val) => val.id === resultFinal);
```

При первом срабатывании, к примеру, выходит такой результат:

```js
[{id: 1, title: 'яблоко', price: 61, photo: 'img/cards/card3.jpg'}]
```

При втором:

```js
[{id: 4, title: 'вишня', price: 169, photo: 'img/cards/card4.jpg'}]
```

и т.д.
Как мне объединить эти массивы в один и получить суммарную стоимость?

Изначально работаем с массивом объектов:

```js
const cards = [
  {
   id: 1, title: 'яблоко', price: 61, photo: 'img/cards/card1.jpg'},
   id: 2, title: 'банан', price: 69, photo: 'img/cards/card2.jpg'},
   id: 3, title: 'киви', price: 119, photo: 'img/cards/card3.jpg'},
   id: 4, title: 'вишня', price: 169, photo: 'img/cards/card4.jpg'
  },....
]
```

Comment: Можете пояснить, что значит первый вызов, второй? Как они связаны друг с другом, Как их объединять вы хотите?

Comment: Приведенный пример "массива объектов" (который `cards`) вообще синтаксически невозможен.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cards = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'яблоко',
    price: 61,
    photo: 'img/cards/card1.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'банан',
    price: 69,
    photo: 'img/cards/card2.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'киви',
    price: 119,
    photo: 'img/cards/card3.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'вишня',
    price: 169,
    photo: 'img/cards/card4.jpg'
  }
]

let arrResults = [];

let prices = [];


//ищем объект с заданым id
function searhById(placeForSearh, id) {
  return placeForSearh.filter((val) => val.id === id);
}

//добавляем результат поиска в отдельный массив
function addSearhToArr(arr, searchResult) {
  return arr.concat(searchResult)
}

//ищем значения сумм объектов в массиве
function sumsPrice(arrSource, arrTarget, keyName) {
  return arrSource.forEach(item => arrTarget.push(item[keyName]));
}

//суммируем массив значений
function getSumValues(arrSource) {
  return arrSource.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
}


arrResults = addSearhToArr(arrResults, searhById(cards, 1));
sumsPrice(cards, prices, 'price')


console.log(arrResults);
console.log(prices);
console.log(getSumValues(prices));
```

Это имелось ввиду?
P.S. Обрати внимание на свой массив "cards", скобки неверны.

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто:

1. Объявляем изначально пустой массив `results`, куда будем складывать результаты нашей фильтрации
2. Добавляем в этот массив не просто результат, т.к. результат - это массив, а добавлем элементы результата с помощью [синтаксиса spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
3. С помощью [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) легко [вычисляем сумму](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value)

```js
const cards = [
   {id: 1, title: 'яблоко', price: 61, photo: 'img/cards/card1.jpg'},
   {id: 2, title: 'банан', price: 69, photo: 'img/cards/card2.jpg'},
   {id: 3, title: 'киви', price: 119, photo: 'img/cards/card3.jpg'},
   {id: 4, title: 'вишня', price: 169, photo: 'img/cards/card4.jpg'},
];

const filterById = (arr, id) => arr.filter(elem => elem.id === id);

const results = [];

const needToFind = [1, 3, 4];

needToFind.forEach(id => results.push(...filterById(cards, id)));

const sum = results.reduce((sum, elem) => sum + elem.price, 0);

console.log(results);
console.log(sum);
```

**P.S.** Если `id` всех объектов уникальны, то вместо `filter` лучше использовать [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Тогда вы будете получать не массив с одним объектом, а сам объект и код станет чутка лечге (не нужен будет `синтаксис spread`):

```js
const cards = [
   {id: 1, title: 'яблоко', price: 61, photo: 'img/cards/card1.jpg'},
   {id: 2, title: 'банан', price: 69, photo: 'img/cards/card2.jpg'},
   {id: 3, title: 'киви', price: 119, photo: 'img/cards/card3.jpg'},
   {id: 4, title: 'вишня', price: 169, photo: 'img/cards/card4.jpg'},
];

const findById = (arr, id) => arr.find(elem => elem.id === id);

const results = [];

const needToFind = [1, 3, 4];

needToFind.forEach(id => results.push(findById(cards, id)));

const sum = results.reduce((sum, elem) => sum + elem.price, 0);

console.log(results);
console.log(sum);
```